# How to morph between shapes

Tags: keyframes, shape-keys

I am trying to make a keyframe pair where an object like this:[image: First]

Becomes an object like this:[image]

I tried to keyframe the two shapes with any frick keying set but it's either useless or "no context info available".
The initial shape is a plane that i extrude with Object Edit mode and then move two vertexs to make the end result. Anybody knowing how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried shapekeys?

Answer (score 9):

You want [*Shapekeys*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/introduction.html#workflow) in this case.

---

First add a basis key as shown below.

[image]

Next, add a second key, and then go to *edit mode*, add edit the object to the second shape with the second key selected.

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]